# Is it possible to create never crashing python code with exception handling?

Tags: python, try-catch, simplehttpserver

I wonder if the below python code (specifically http server) ever crashes? Assuming that there is no grammer error in any of the library code(already compiled), what I think that handling the exceptions in a while loop should be sufficient for this code not to crash anytime. I tried the below code for a while and never crashed, but I wonder if theoretically or practically possible for this program to crash?

```
while True:
    try:

        server = HTTPServer(('', PORT_NUMBER), myHandler)
        server.serve_forever()

    except:
        try:
           server.socket.close()
        except:
            pass
```

The actual reason I am asking this question that I don't want to deal with UNIX staff to watch the process and restart it if it crashes. Is the above solution sufficient? 
Thanks.

Comment: `Socket.close()` could raise an exception in some edge cases.

Comment: @KlausD. Can you give an example of such a case?

Comment: The Socket has been closed by the OS for any reason.

Comment: I edited to code in question, so please forget about server.socket.close() line

Comment: While you will now stay inside the loop, it is not guaranteed that the code really works. If it raises an exception it will be stuck in a loop without ever working. And no tool (like `supervisord` explained below) will notice. It will most likely just occupy one CPU core.

Answer (score 0):

If "except" block has worng code, it can crash cause of it. I mean, something like that:

```
# path/to/py3
FOO = [1,2,3]
try:
  # index out of bound, try block has error, so it goes ahead and executes except-block
  print(FOO[4])
except:
  # if there is some kind of error, like Syntax error, program can crash
  print "Index out of bound!"
  print("2"+2)
  print(FOO["BAR"])
```

but if exception block has the correct logic too, then programm should work without crashing

Comment: Except clause has only this line and one can assume it never throws: 
 server.socket.close()

Answer (score 0):

Like Klaus D. already mentioned in his comment, there can be cases where the socket close code in your except block crashes.  You could optionally also throw a try except around that as well...

Another option is to use something like this (no UNIX involved):

http://supervisord.org/

It's easy to run and will automatically restart your program if it crashes.